# Can a closed app have access to the screen even if another app is open?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Hi I'm new to app development and I've been wondering if an app that's closed or not open can still show things on your screen even if you have another app open. For instance if I'm on safari, can another app open a temporary screen (showing a picture for a few seconds). I know there is push notifications but this is only a bar on top of your screen and heavily controlled by the OS.
Thanks!

The only thing I could find that was equivalent was push notifications. Is there a different permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about IOS , but in android there is a permission called 'Draw over other apps' which precisely does what you intent to . You should check that out.

Comment: That's very useful thank you. I was unable to find a similar permission for IOS so I don't think it's possible